# Type mismatch during refactoring using Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following piece of code I'd like to make DRYer:

```
def createAdmin(/* ... */): Future[Int] =
  db.run {
    {
      (users returning users.map(_.id)) += Account(0, /* ... */)
    } flatMap { id =>
      admins += Admin(userId = id, /* ... */)
    }
  }

def createStandardUser(/* ... */): Future[Int] =
  db.run {
    {
      (users returning users.map(_.id)) += Account(0, /* ... */)
    } flatMap { id =>
      standardUsers += StandardUser(userId = id, /* ... */)
    }
  }
```

That compiles fine.  But if I consolidate the two into the following:

```
def createUser(role: String)(/* ... */): Future[Int] =
  db.run {
    {
      (users returning users.map(_.id)) += Account(0, /* ... */)
    } flatMap { id =>
      role match {
        case "admin" =>
          admins += Admin(userId = id, /* ... */)
        case "standard" =>
          standardUsers += StandardUser(userId = id, /* ... */)
      }
    }
  }
```

I get the following type mismatch error:

```
[error]  found   : Long => slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]
[error]  required: Long => slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,E2]
[error]       } flatMap { id =>
[error]                      ^
[error] one error found
```

I can't seem to figure out why.  Can someone illuminate this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler can't figure out the used effect type correctly. As a workaround you should be able to give it some help by specifiying types used, e.g. in the flatMap operation, which would be

```
flatMap[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] { id =>
```

in your case.

Comment: This works!  Alternatively, one can replace the `flatMap[...]` with `map` and change the return type of the method to `Future[Unit]` if the return type isn't needed (which is the case for me).

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't refactor the code that way.
I know that from the point of view of the code it looks reasonable. But the pattern matching in the `flatMap` doesn't give enough information to the compiler to infer the [effect](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.dbio.Effect) to the [DBIOAction](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/#slick.dbio.DBIOAction).

As you can read in the [source code](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/408f2e55aa0a7553a445c83b7ee5ef159f805694/slick/src/main/scala/slick/dbio/DBIOAction.scala):

> When composing actions, the correct combined effect type will be inferred

So in other words, as Slick doesn't know what are you going to do after the first insertion in compilation time, the compilation fails. And [as the documentation says](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/dbio.html), "it is not possible to fuse this actions for more efficient execution".

Comment: Can I somehow specify that the bodies of the two `case` branches return `Unit`, therefore making explicit that both return types are ignored (but more importantly, that both types are the same, thereby appeasing the compiler)?

Comment: Also, I couldn't find in the link you gave the statement, "it is not possible to fuse this actions for more efficient execution."  Am I missing something?

Comment: Well they don't return unit, they return DBIOAction (which is what you need to return from the flatMap). However you should be able to give the compiler some help with the types to get around this, e.g. by specifying the types used in the flatMap operation, which would be  `flatMap[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] { id =>` in your case if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @alextsc This is the correct answer.  Thank you.  If you write this as an answer, I'll mark as answered.

Comment: @alextsc I've been viewing `flatMap` as an operator for so long instead of a method that I forgot I could attach type parameters to it!

Comment: Well it's technically just a workaround and the correct answer is Carlos one here, "it doesnt work because the compiler cant figure out the types". However I'll post my comment as an answer so it doesnt get lost on anybody who is looking for a practical solution.